# Composer runtime installation failed while deploying on IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-composer

I'm following  [this](https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/platform-deployment/)  tutorial to deploy my business network on the IBM Blockchain Platform. However, at the instruction :

> composer network deploy -c  -a myNetwork.bna -A admin -C ~/.identityCredentials/admin-pub.pem -f delete_me.card

I have the following error message :

> Installing runtime for business network undefined. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: Error: Invalid results returned ::NOT_FOUND

Any idea on what should I do ? In fact I didn't understand the purpose of composer runtime if anybody has explanations for me it would be great !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that instruction is incorrect.

You would do a

```
composer runtime install -n biznet-name -c admin.card
```

where 'admin.card' is created from:

```
composer card create -f admin.card -p connection.json -u admin -c ~/.identityCredentials/admin-pub.pem  -k ~/.identityCredentials/admin-priv.pem -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin
```

ie including the connection.json file that has the right endpoint values from your Service Credentials information provided by IBP. You build the card, so that you can install the runtime, then instantiate it on the channel defined in your connection.json.

(additionally, you would have imported that card and connected to the business network to download credentials to the wallet eg.):

```
composer card import -f admin.card
composer network ping -c admin@mynetwork   (whatever you called it)
```

Finally, after the `runtime install` command, you would do something like the following to instantiate/start your business network on the channel :

```
composer network start -n mynetwork -a mynetwork.bna -A admin -S -c admin@mynetwork
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give it a try !